# When div is toggled, already toggled divs untoggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stuck with some code and I'm not clear as to how to go about making it function without writing a massive amount of code.
The idea is that when one div is toggled to display a hidden text, when you click on another div, that one un-toggles and only shows the other one.
I know how to do it manually (using a boat load of code) but I was wondering if there is maybe a "general" line of code I can just paste behind each it.

Here's my JS:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bioInfo').on('click', function(){
    $('#bioInfoText').toggle();
  });
     $('#bioTech').on('click', function(){
    $('#bioInfoText').toggle();
  });
    $('#bioFuture').on('click', function(){
    $('#bioFutureText').toggle();
  });
    $('#bioCont').on('click', function(){
    $('#bioContText').toggle();
  });
    $('#bioAdd').on('click', function(){
    $('#bioAddText').toggle();
  });
    $('#bioPrac').on('click', function(){
    $('#bioPracText').toggle();
  });
     $('#automInfo').on('click', function(){
    $('#automInfoText').toggle();
  });
    $('#automFuture').on('click', function(){
    $('#automFutureText').toggle();
  });
     $('#autom').on('click', function(){
    $('#automInfoText').toggle();
  });
    $('#automContent').on('click', function(){
    $('#automContentText').toggle();
  });
    $('#automAdd').on('click', function(){
    $('#automAddText').toggle();
  });
    $('#automPrac').on('click', function(){
    $('#automPracText').toggle();
  });
     $('#itInfo').on('click', function(){
    $('#itInfoText').toggle();
  });
     $('#it').on('click', function(){
    $('#itInfoText').toggle();
  });
    $('#itFuture').on('click', function(){
    $('#itFutureText').toggle();
  });
    $('#itCont').on('click', function(){
    $('#itContText').toggle();
  });
    $('#itAdd').on('click', function(){
    $('#itAddText').toggle();
  });
    $('#itPrac').on('click', function(){
    $('#itPracText').toggle();
  });
```

As you can see it toggles one by one, but only toggles off if I click on that individual div manually, this is not desired.

Comment: I am aware of that, I'm just trying to see which solution works, thus far none of them are actually doing the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to have it in a different implementation. For the solution, here, use a reset function:

```
function resetAll() {
  $('[id$="Text"]').hide();
  // Translates to:
  $("#bioInfoText, #bioInfoText, #bioFutureText, #bioContText, #bioAddText, #bioPracText, #automInfoText, #automFutureText, #automInfoText, #automContentText, #automAddText, #automPracText, #itInfoText, #itInfoText, #itFutureText, #itContText, #itAddText, #itPracText").hide();
}
```

And then call the `resetAll()` function in every click.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would just add a class to the elements you want to work with. Then you can do something like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.someClass', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.someClass').hide();
    $('.someClass #' + id + 'Text').show(); // Following your naming convention 
});
```

Now I don't know how your html looks so I can't say if it is 100% correct... but I think you get the idea.